# Check if the user is activate or not

Tags: database, session, authentication, registration

Am trying to develop a login/registration system so the user must activate its account. My problem is how to check in the database for the column 'activate' which is 0 if it's not activate and 1 if his/her account is active, plus i want to put an if it's not active to display a message.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * WHERE username2='$username2' AND activation=0";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
if($result2=1){
    echo"Please activate your account"; 
}
else{
    echo " ";
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: you can maybe use where statement and in the parameter you can out something like this ...  activate = '1'  something like that

Comment: That's what i thought to use, a select statement but i don't know the syntax, like a select the username using the session variable username and check if activate is 0 show "not activate"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function function_name ($username){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('table_name'); // table_name where you can find the column username and activation
  $this->db->where(array('username' => $username , 'activate' => 0)); // condition use  if the user is active or not

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->return_array(); // you can also use here first_row('array')

}
```

I hope this helps .